# R Vectorized numbering of rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large ordered dataframe consisting of a number of related records.  For each group of related records, I need to number them from 1 to the total number of related records.  If I iterate over the whole dataframe, the operation takes too long.

I'm wondering if there is a vectorized way to do this?

For example, if I had this dataframe:

```
ID  Month    State
1   Apr-2014  AL
2   May-2014  AL
3   Jun-2014  AL
4   Apr-2014  MN
5   May-2014  MN
6   Apr-2014  FL
7   May-2014  FL
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
ID  Month    State  Seq
1   Apr-2014  AL    1
2   May-2014  AL    2
3   Jun-2014  AL    3
4   Apr-2014  MN    1
5   May-2014  MN    2
6   Apr-2014  FL    1
7   May-2014  FL    2
```

Comment: There are quick and efficient ways to achieve this with `data.table` or `dplyr`. Could you post some example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example dataset.  If the dataset is ordered, you can compare the previous row of `Month` with the current row and check if they differ.  Below code, I removed the first observation `df$Month[-1]` and compared with the ones with last observation removed `df$Month[-nrow(df)]` so that the `lengths` are equal.  By using `!=`, we get `TRUE` for values that are different.  Concatenate with `TRUE` at the beginning and do `cumsum` to get the `index`.

```
 df$Seq <- cumsum(c(TRUE,df$Month[-1]!= df$Month[-nrow(df)]))
 df
 #  ID    Month State Seq
 #1  1 Apr-2014    AL   1
 #2  2 Apr-2014    MN   1
 #3  3 Apr-2014    FL   1
 #4  4 May-2014    AL   2
 #5  5 May-2014    MN   2
 #6  6 May-2014    FL   2
 #7  7 Jun-2014    AL   3
```

Or you can convert the `Month` column to `factor` and reconvert it back to `numeric`.

```
 as.numeric(factor(df$Month, levels=unique(df$Month)))
 #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
  DT <- setDT(df)[, Seq:= .GRP, by=Month]
  DT
  #   ID    Month State Seq
  #1:  1 Apr-2014    AL   1
  #2:  2 Apr-2014    MN   1
  #3:  3 Apr-2014    FL   1
  #4:  4 May-2014    AL   2
  #5:  5 May-2014    MN   2
  #6:  6 May-2014    FL   2
  #7:  7 Jun-2014    AL   3
```

`.GRP` is a special variable. Have a look at `?data.table` to read more about it.

#### data

```
 df <-  structure(list(ID = 1:7, Month = c("Apr-2014", "Apr-2014", "Apr-2014", 
"May-2014", "May-2014", "May-2014", "Jun-2014"), State = c("AL", 
 "MN", "FL", "AL", "MN", "FL", "AL")), .Names = c("ID", "Month", 
 "State"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the actual seq number you could simply do:

```
df$Seq <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Month))
df
#   ID    Month State Seq
# 1  1 Apr-2014    AL   1
# 2  2 Apr-2014    MN   1
# 3  3 Apr-2014    FL   1
# 4  4 May-2014    AL   3
# 5  5 May-2014    MN   3
# 6  6 May-2014    FL   3
# 7  7 Jun-2014    AL   2
```

If you care about the actual number in Seq (i.e. that it is in order), you should use something like:

```
month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
df$part1 <- with(df, factor(gsub("([^\\-]*).*", "\\1", Month), month))
df$part2 <- with(df, factor(gsub("[^\\-]*\\-(.*)", "\\1", Month)))
df$whole <- with(df, interaction(part1, part2, drop = TRUE, lex.order = FALSE))
df$Seq <- as.numeric(df$whole)
#   ID    Month State part1 part2    whole Seq
# 1  1 Apr-2014    AL   Apr  2014 Apr.2014   1
# 2  2 Apr-2014    MN   Apr  2014 Apr.2014   1
# 3  3 Apr-2014    FL   Apr  2014 Apr.2014   1
# 4  4 May-2014    AL   May  2014 May.2014   2
# 5  5 May-2014    MN   May  2014 May.2014   2
# 6  6 May-2014    FL   May  2014 May.2014   2
# 7  7 Jun-2014    AL   Jun  2014 Jun.2014   3
```